# jquery-ui dialog (save position via php) - only works with .draggable not .dialog

Tags: php, jquery-ui

I'm trying to store the user position + size of my jquery-ui dialogs to a mysql db. I tried reading the manual here: https://api.jqueryui.com/1.10/dialog/ and there was no documentation of how to do this. The issue with my code below is      $data = json_decode($_POST["data"]); in savelayout.php returns NULL.

**Edit:** I was able to get the coordinates to store to mysql via PHP post this way, however they're always the same size `3.078125` and `38.453125`. `alert(JSON.stringify(order));` always outputs the same coordinates as well, despite using `var coord = $(this).position();`

**Edit:** Using .draggable works but not .dialog

**Edit:** Added more broken code.  Whatever.
Example dialogue (draggable + resizable):

```
       <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {



        $("#menu").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        position: {my: 'left <?php echo $menumy; ?>', at: 'left <?php echo $menuat; ?>', of: window},
        modal: false,
        height: <?php echo $menuheight; ?>,
        width: <?php echo $menuwidth; ?>,
        dialogClass: 'fixed-dialog',
        dragStop: function(e, ui) { saveCoords(ui.offset.top, ui.offset.left); },
                      resize: function( event, ui ) {
                      $( this ).dialog( "option",
                 ui.size.height + " x " + ui.size.width );

                $.post("savelayout.php", { menuheight: ui.size.height, menuwidth: ui.size.width } );
                   }
         }).mousemove(function(){
                var coord = $(this).position();
                $("p:last").text( "left: " + coord.left + ", top: " + coord.top );

         }).mouseup(function(){
                var coords=[];
                var coord = $(this).position();
                var item={ coordTop:  coord.left, coordLeft: coord.top  };
                coords.push(item);
                var order = { coords: coords };

                });

        });


    function saveCoords(top, left) {
      $.post(
        "savelayout.php",
        JSON.stringify({
          coordtop: Math.round(top),
          coordleft: Math.round(left)
        })
      );
    }
        </script>
```

Comment: What event would trigger the saving of the dialog position and size? Upon Opening? Drag? Close? Once you have picked a trigger, you can then execute code at that time to save the details you'd like.

Comment: Would it be more logical for the trigger to be Time based via setTimeout\setInterval or per Drag+Resize. I'm concerned about cpu usage.

Comment: If that is the concern, why not store it in a cookie versus browser memory? Without knowing the use case, I can't really advise. How often is the position needed? What happens if the user changes the position? Whats the end goal?

Comment: Right on. Will look at it tomorrow and see if I can offer assistance.

Comment: When I use .draggable I can get the coordinates but not with .dialog weird

Comment: What do you see when you add in dialog `dragStart: function(e, ui) { console.log(ui.position); }`

Comment: Object {top: 0, left: 0} at first then after i move it once
(index):476 Object {top: 207, left: 489}
(index):476 Object {top: 117, left: 184}
(index):476 Object {top: 68, left: 501}

Comment: Ok, looking at your code a bit again, do you want this when the dialog is moved? If so, `dragStop` might be better. I also think the `ui.offset` might be better to store. Will write up a way to do this and how to recover it properly.

Comment: Yeah soon as the dialog is done being moved I want to send the x y coordinate to php via post so it seems like dragStop is the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so when you move a dialog, you can do this to capture the `top` (y) and `left` (x) values.

```
function saveCoords(top, left) {
  $.post(
    "savelayout.php",
    JSON.stringify({
      coordtop: Math.round(top),
      coordleft: Math.round(left)
    })
  );
}

$("#menu").dialog({
    bgiframe: true,
    position: {
      my: 'left top',
      at: 'left top',
      of: window
    },
    modal: false,
    dialogClass: 'fixed-dialog',
    dragStop: function(e, ui) {
      saveCoords(ui.offset.top, ui.offset.left);
    }
  });
```

When you go to create the Dialog again, and you want to position it back from your values, use `position` like so:

```
<?php
// Collect value from MySQL and enter it into an array
$menu = array("at" => array("top" => 0, "left" => 0));
?>

position: {
  my: 'left top',
  at: 'left+<?php echo $menu['at']['left']; ?> top+<?php echo $menu['at']['top']; ?>',
  of: window
}
```

You can improve this a little with a check:

```
position: {
  my: 'left top',
  at: 'left<?php echo isset($menu['at']['left']) ? '+'.$menu['at']['left'] : ''; ?> top<?php echo isset($menu['at']['top']) ? '+'.$menu['at']['top'] : ''; ?>',
  of: window
}
```

Personally, I would feed it into a globally defined variable.

Here is a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/d9ff1LLu/

**HTML**

```
<div id="results" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
<button id="remake">Remake Dialog</button>
<div id="menu" title="menu title"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#results {
  height: 2em;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var menu = {
  at: {
    top: 0,
    left: 0
  }
}

function saveCoords(top, left) {
  $.post("/echo/json/", {
    json: JSON.stringify({
      coordtop: Math.round(top),
      coordleft: Math.round(left)
    })
  }, function(results) {
    menu.at.top = results.coordtop;
    menu.at.left = results.coordleft;
    $("#results").html("Recorded { top: " + results.coordtop + ", left: " + results.coordleft + "}");
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#remake").button().click(function() {
    $("#menu").dialog("close");
    $("#menu").remove();
    $("#results").html("Removed Menu. Creating new at position: 'top+" + menu.at.top + " left+" + menu.at.left + "'");
    var menuDialog = $("<div>", {
      id: "menu",
      title: "New Menu Title"
    }).dialog({
      bgiframe: true,
      position: {
        my: 'left top',
        at: 'left' + (menu.at.left > 0 ? "+" + menu.at.left : '') + ' top' + (menu.at.top > 0 ? "+" + menu.at.top : ''),
        of: window
      },
      modal: false,
      dialogClass: 'fixed-dialog'
    });
  });
  $("#menu").dialog({
    bgiframe: true,
    position: {
      my: 'left top',
      at: 'left top',
      of: window
    },
    modal: false,
    dialogClass: 'fixed-dialog',
    dragStop: function(e, ui) {
      saveCoords(ui.offset.top, ui.offset.left);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: this is amazing let me read it over and take it all in thank you

Comment: For some reason I'm getting Recorded { top: undefined, left: undefined} when I use your example.

Comment: If you could modify my example above that would be great. I'm just about to give up.

Comment: Can you edit your post again and include the code you're using now? Don't give up, the answer is there. You'll get it.

Comment: I accidentally clicked Save when I was closing Pluma and that's unfortunately my current code.

Comment: The code above does contain dragStop shouldn't it be sending it to the function saveCoords(top, left) and then sending it via PHP (POST)? For some reason the output is NULL.

Comment: Right. So either saveCoords is getting null. What info is sent back by your php script? Or maybe we should just use top and left values that are sent saveCoords.